# USB HID communication using C# ReadAsync method seems impossible to cancel

Tags: c#, asynchronous, usb, hid

I have a C# application which communicates with an equipment through USB using the HID class.

To read from the device, I'm using the ReadAsync function with a timeout cancellation token, based on the Jan's Axelson code - http://janaxelson.com/hidpage.htm

```
            _transferInProgress = true;

            readCTS = new CancellationTokenSource();

            Action onReadTimeoutAction = OnReadTimeout;

            readCTS.CancelAfter(timeout);

            readCTS.Token.Register(onReadTimeoutAction);

            Task<Int32> t = _deviceData.ReadAsync(inputReportBuffer, 0, inputReportBuffer.Length, readCTS.Token);
            bytesRead = await t;

            readCTS.Dispose();

            _transferInProgress = false;

            return bytesRead;
```

In this application it's normal to the host (PC) request some data but the device (equipment) never answer it. When it happens, the ReadAsync don't seems to be cancelled by the timeout. The I also tried tho call _deviceData.Close() on the OnReadTimeout function (which IS called), but it doesn't make the ReadAsync to stop. So, no matter what I do, the code never reaches the line with "readCTS.Dispose();", I put a breakpoint on it and I see that it's never called.

I need a way to stop the ReadAsync, because sometimes the device won't send data.

EDIT: The code for OnReadTimeout:

```
private void OnReadTimeout()
    {
        _transferInProgress = false;
        _deviceData.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code for `OnReadTimeout`

Comment: The *convention* for most `FILE`-based Win32 I/O APIs is to cancel any outstanding reads/writes when that handle is closed. However, AFAIK there's nothing in the system to *force* this. So I'd say the best people to ask is the C# library or device driver author.

Comment: Are you sure it's not cancelling? Awaiting a cancelled task should throw a [TaskCanceledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcanceledexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which would explain why your readCTS.Dispose() breakpoint is never hit.

Comment: @Mark: I'm not a very experienced C# programmer. As far as I know, if I'm not catching exceptions, when they happen they should interrupt the software and show a windows error message, isn't it? Well, I don't get any exception error message when running this code.